# What does "catch the sun" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases

What does *catch the sun* mean?

Comment: I guess you’re not thinking of *“Wild men who caught and sang the sun in flight”*, right?  :-P

Comment: I've also heard _catch some rays_ to mean the same thing as sunbathing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It generally means that you're looking a little sunburnt.

Comment: Is the past tense used, in this case?

Comment: Yes, normally something like, "Ooooh, it looks like you've caught the sun!". As someone who burns easily, I've had this said to me on a few occasions. :-S

Answer (score 10):

A corner of a garden, or a balconey can 'catch the sun' if it's correctly positioned and not overshadowed.

Answer (score 5):

I have heard Americans use this phrase.  It generally means *sunbathe* ("I'm gonna catch some sun this weekend").

Comment: The _Corpus of Contemporary American English_ reports the phrase _catch the sun_.

Comment: The Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English entry reports "catch the sun" as British English and "get some sun" as American English.

http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/sun_1

if someone catches or gets the sun, they become slightly red or brown because they have been outside in the sun

Comment: Crucially, "catch some sun" in this meaning in America, not "catch the sun".

Comment: You're right, you're all right.  I answered the question I heard in my head, not the question he actually wrote.

Comment: I've never heard it to mean sunbathe. If you've caught some sun you're a bit sunburnt, probably unintentionally.

Comment: @TRiG -- that's sarcasm, like telling someone with a hangover "You look like you had a good time."  "Catch some sun" and "catch some rays" mean sunbathe just as "catch some sleep" (or "zzzs" or "shuteye") means take a nap.

Comment: @Malviolio, It looks like there's a difference between catching some sun and catching the sun. *You've caught the sun a bit there* means you're sunburnt.

Answer (score 3):

If you live in the the Northwest, you may leave work a little early during the winter in order to "catch the sun."